# The property could not be found in Razor view interface model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, interface

Why am I getting this error below for a parent interface property?

```
The property IStoreRegistrationPayment.PaymentSelection could not be found.
```

**RegistrationPayment.cshtml**

```
@model IStoreRegistrationPayment
@Html.Partial(MVC.Event.Views.Controls.PaymentSelection, Model)
```

**PaymentSelection.cshtml**

```
@model IStoreRegistrationPayment

@Html.HiddenFor(q => q.PaymentSelection)
```

**IStoreRegistrationPayment.cs**

```
public interface IStoreRegistrationPayment : IPaymentSelection
{
}
```

**IPaymentSelection.cs**

```
public interface IPaymentSelection
{
    bool PaymentSelection { get; set; }
}
```

The only thing that worked was to do this

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(q => ((IPaymentSelection)q).PaymentSelection)
```

Comment: Can you share the source code when you assign the model to this view?

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Your code works without any errors, for me at least.

Comment: I added the calling PartialView also